# How to make ResourceHttpRequestHandler a priority over a parametrized controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to serve static assets under `/static/**` URLs while I have a controller with `RequestMapping("/{group}/{item}")`. So when I try to request, for example, `/static/main.css`, it routes me to my controller with `group = "static", item = "main.css"`, which is what I don't want.

Example application:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/{group}/{item}")
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hello(@PathVariable("group") String group, @PathVariable("item") String item) {
        return "Hello %s/%s".formatted(group, item);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to deprecate `/static/**` URLs for the controller, or probably prioritize resource handler over the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer. The key was to add `@EnableWebMvc` and `setOrder`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setOrder(-1)
                .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```